# How to reference lagged interaction coefficient in stata estout? (error "coefficient not found")

Tags: stata, panel-data

I have a (perhaps) simple question regarding estout in Stata:

I have a panel dataset and want to export regression tables via estout, but only keep some coefficients. The problem I have come across is that I do not understand how to reference coefficients that are 1) lagged AND 2) interactions. For each case individually, the esttab works fine, but when I try both, the coefficient is "not found" (Stata error term).

Example:

```
clear 
ssc install estout

input float(code year var1 var2 var3)
1 2000 1 2 3 
1 2001 45 5555 8
1 2002 3 3 3
2 2000 11 8 9 
2 2001 2 1 12
2 2002 3 4 11111
3 2000 4 77 1
3 2001 3 99 3
3 2002 111 9 20
end

xtset code year
eststo: xtpcse var1 l.c.var2##l.c.var3
esttab using example.rtf, keep(l.c.var2#l.c.var3) replace
```

Without the lagged variables in the interaction, "c.var2#c.var3" in the keep() command works fine. Without the interaction, "l.var2" in the keep() command works as well. In combination, I receive an error...

This issue seems so simple, yet I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe the coefficient name as it appears in the regression output:

```
eststo: xtpcse var1 l.c.var2##l.c.var3

Linear regression, correlated panels corrected standard errors (PCSEs)

Group variable:   code                          Number of obs     =          6
Time variable:    year                          Number of groups  =          3
Panels:           correlated (balanced)         Obs per group:
Autocorrelation:  no autocorrelation                          min =          2
                                                              avg =          2
                                                              max =          2
Estimated covariances      =         6          R-squared         =     0.2801
Estimated autocorrelations =         0          Wald chi2(3)      =      29.28
Estimated coefficients     =         4          Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                |           Panel-corrected
           var1 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           var2 |
            L1. |   .3047307   .7251617     0.42   0.674     -1.11656    1.726022
                |
           var3 |
            L1. |  -2.842736   1.995148    -1.42   0.154    -6.753154    1.067682
                |
cL.var2#cL.var3 |  -.0384245   .0907775    -0.42   0.672    -.2163452    .1394962
                |
          _cons |   40.83134   12.87304     3.17   0.002     15.60066    66.06203
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Following this up with `esttab using example.rtf, keep(cL.var2#cL.var3) replace` works for me.